# Select specified text from JSON column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table, for example `writing` in psql. This table has a column `json` (`text` type). It contains text like this:

```
writing:[{"variableName":variableValue ...}]
```

variableValues are different types, including `text` ,`bigint` and `date`.

I want to get all rows from `writing` where `variableName` has the value 2.

I'm using this select:

```
select * from writing where json::json->>'variableName' = '2' limit 5
```

This select returns me 0 rows, but there are a lot of data in this table, which should pass this condition. Any idea what is wrong, or maybe you have better statement.

*Im using limit 5 because need just 5 rows.*

Comment: Unrelated, but: JSON data is best stored in a column defined as `jsonb`, not as `text`. Then you would notice that  `writing:[{"variableName":variableValue ...}]` is not a valid JSON value.

Comment: Noticed that but data structure is far beyond so changing that will be way too time consuming. Anyway I appreciate the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to prepend a `{` and append a `}` to make it a JSON like you intend. As it is, it will become a single JSON string.

Then you'll have to access the attribute as

```
('{' || json || '}')::json->'writing'->1->>'variableName'
```

Comment: With Your example it pop out that argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type text because as u said it will become a single JSON string.

Comment: Right. Your condition would then be `WHERE /* my expression */ = '2'`.

Comment: Ye. Now everything is working as it should. Much thanks for help. Have one question for your statement what exactly is doing 1 in 'writing'->1->>'variableName'

Comment: It gets the first element of a JSON array (the `[...]`).